# AchartEngine Date on X-Axis, format bugs

Tags: android, date, format, achartengine

I'm using AchartEngine, and I want the time on the X-axis, but with the method add.(Date, double), I have number like this : "1374740271000" on the x-axis. How can I do to have it in HH-MM-SS ?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to build a `TimeChart` instead of a `LineChart` in order to get formatted date on the X axis. Another solution is to add custom text labels:

```
renderer.addXTextLabel(x, text);
```

Comment: Yes thank you I forgot that ...

mChartView = ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(this, mDataset, mRenderer,
                "H:mm:ss");

Thanks, problem solved.

Comment: You probably have very close date values and the format you have chosen won't make a difference between the formatted dates.

Comment: I found the problem, I take my points in a 'for' loop so the points have the same date, I have to change the place where I take the date.